# Create a new workbook, import Macro and assign button

Tags: vba, excel

I've created some VBA code to create new workbook, spawn some worksheet elements and import a code module.

Then I want to link the button to the macros in the newly created file using those imported modules.

Instead VBA is trying to assign the button of the newly created file to the macros in the workbook running the code, rather than the destination file itself.

I'm using a line:

```
destwb.Worksheets(newSheetName).Shapes("Button 1").OnAction = "Test_Button_Press"
```

Where **destwb** is the new workbook object and **newSheetName** is the name of the sheet in this new book containing these elements.

Is there some code that I can use to replace **"Test_Button_Press"** with something more explicit of the workbook then its codename? i.e. **destwb."Test_Button_Press"** sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
destwb.Worksheets(newSheetName).Shapes("Button 1").OnAction = destwb.Name & "!Test_Button_Press"
```

So that the OnAction string includes the name of the new workbook, an exclamation mark and then the name of the macro.

Comment: Sorry its taken so long to reply.  Just gave this a try and it didn't work. The only solution i've found so far has been to hand code a macro that attaches to the button and runs the expected macro that way.

Comment: I now know why.  The code i'd created was making an OLE object (because i had so much trouble originally) which isn't the same as the shape object.  If i make a shape object i can do exactly as you have described.